# How to make clickable cards using Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using `bootstrap-4` and I want to make clickable cards, but for some reason when I do:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 mx-lg-auto col-xl-6">
     <div class="card card--industry mb-4">
         <a href="{{ $industry->url }}" class="card-block">
             <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                   <img src="{{ asset('storage/'. $industry->icon) }}" class="card-img rounded-0" alt="{{ $industry->name }}" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                   <div class="card-body">
                       <h3 class="card-title">{!! $industry->link !!}</h3>
                       <div class="card-text">
                          {!! $industry->short_description !!}
                       </div>
                       <a href="{{ $industry->url }}" class="card-link d-block mt-4">Read more</a>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

It totally f***s up the DOM but I'm not missing any closing tags, so I was wondering if there is something about clickable cards using bootstrap?

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has a functionality for that:

[Bootstrap stretched link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/stretched-link/)

Another option is use the card class in a link tag with `text-decoration-none`. Then, the entire card is a link:

[Example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ctLpbwd3/)

Comment: Yes, since the link is in a column, I needed to add `position-static` to the column and `position-relative` to the `.row` to make it work :-)

Comment: Yes it is :-) Thanks for the tip!